# Why android File.delete() , File.rename() fails on some devices?

Tags: android, file, rename

It works on my nexus 5,but not working on samsung devices and some OEM devices.

This is my code:

```
 File f = new File(path);
        if (f.exists()) {

            if (f.delete()) {
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx, new String[]{path, ""}, null, null);
            } else {
                // Log.e(TAG, ctx.getString(R.string.unableToDelete));
            }

        } else { Toast.makeText(ctx,ctx.getString(R.string.fileNotFound),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Have you added Write Permission to your manifest?

Comment: Yes.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: [The doc says: *"Note that the Files class defines the delete method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted."*](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete()), so maybe use `Files#delete` instead of `File#delete` to help debug the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the external storage is still mounted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask to the user if he accept the read/write permission

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,}, 1);
        } else {
            createTemporaryFile();
        }
```

Don't forget to add the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I got an issue with the device on Api > 24 for using file I need to disable the UriExposure

```
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
        try{
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have the write permission granted. My test device api level is 19 and 16.